# how to cast with eq in odata filtering?

Tags: odata

I want to set filters in odata queries with user interaction. When the user selects a data attribute I already know its type. For instance if the user want to filter with SALE_PRICE equal to some number I already know that the selected attribute is of type Edm.Decimal. So I tried to use this fact and build the query with the cast operation. For instance, to get the data where the SALE_PRICE is equal to 323.7 I create the following URI:

```
analyticView?$select=AMOUNT_SOLD,FAMILY_NAME&$filter=SALE_PRICE+eq+(cast(323.7,'Edm.Decimal'))&$format=json
```

but I am getting an error message saying:

```
"No property 'cast' exists in type
```

I also tried this on the serivces.odata.org API, and it doesn't seem to work

http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$select=Freight,OrderID&$filter=OrderDate+eq+(cast(1996-07-05T00:00:00,'Edm.DateTime'))&$top=5&$format=json

could you please check what's wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue I created this [handler](https://gist.github.com/mohamed-ali/6944876)

```
//How to use 
 var test = odataHanlder.odataFilter();

//how to extend with new handler 
test.addFilterHandler("Edm.Int16", function(_value){
return _value;
});

//how to prepare filter on the fly 
console.log(test.prepareFilter("Edm.DateTime","1996-07-04T00:00:00"));
//result >> datetime'1996-07-04T00:00:00'
```

you can find a more detailed description [here](http://intelligea.wordpress.com/2013/10/12/how-to-format-odata-filters-values-on-the-fly-using-their-edm-types/)

feedback is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need the cast? You could try this query instead,

```
analyticView?$select=AMOUNT_SOLD,FAMILY_NAME&$filter=SALE_PRICE eq 323.7M&$format=json
```

You can represent [decimals](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v2-documentation/overview/) by suffixing them with m|M like 3.27M

Comment: thanks for replying, actually that's what I am doing currently. But, the filters are defined by user interaction, one time they can be a decimal, others they can be string, int, or datetime (or any other type supported by OData) and the only time to get the data type is to read the metadata. So the idea is to register the attributes with their types and use that for filtering!

Comment: This is what I've been looking for.  Wish I could buy you a beer somehow.

Answer (score 2):

"1996-07-05T00:00:00" is not a well-formatted datetime constant, it should be "datetime'1996-07-05T00:00:00'"  then this query works:  http://services.odata.org/V3/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Orders?$select=Freight,OrderID&$filter=OrderDate+eq+(cast(datetime'1996-07-05T00:00:00','Edm.DateTime'))&$top=5&$format=json

Not sure why you got error out of your analyticView request. it will be good if you can share more details about the model and error message.

Comment: but this means that once again I have to do some formatting of the value like adding datetime to '1996-07-05T00:00:00' or adding M to 323.7. Aren't there a way, library... that would do this based on the Edm type?

Comment: cast function is like the casting in .net/java, can cast a value to a similar type or derived/base entity type, e.g. (double)12, or (decimal)OrderID, (Employee)person. but doesn't support converting a type (like string) to a different type(like float/double).

Comment: cast is not what I am looking for then, I am looking for a way to prepare the filter based on the Edm type for instance if I have '1996-07-05T00:00:00' with Edm.DateTime the library/solution would do the formatting of the value to give datetime'1996-07-05T00:00:00'. Is there such a solution?

Comment: OData does offer the flexiblity of writing server side function, but it doesn't come for free. so instead of writing server side function, I would suggest you write client side code to do the formatting (assuming you already have the values), the overall cost should be lower than exposing & calling server side function.